# Could a motivic spectrum have a "zeta function"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, zeta-functions, motivic-homotopy

I'm currently learning about zeta functions, so I apologize in advance if this is riddled with nonsense. Suppose you have a sequence $E=(E_0,E_1,...)$ of motivic spaces along with structure maps $s_i:\mathbb{P}^1\wedge E_i\to E_{i+1}$ that induce weak equivalences $\Sigma_{\mathbb{P}^1}E_i\simeq E_{i+1}$, so that $E$ is a motivic spectrum. **Is there a sequence of zeta functions $\zeta_E=(\zeta_{E_0},\zeta_{E_1},...)$ that respects the structure maps?**

There are several pieces of this question that I'm not sure about:

1. If $E_i$ is a projective variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$, then we can assign a local zeta function $\zeta_{E_i}$ to it. Is it possible to do the same for a more general motivic space?
2. If $X$ and $Y$ are motivic spaces that have zeta functions $\zeta_X$ and $\zeta_Y$, is there a zeta function $\zeta_{X\wedge Y}$ for their smash product? If so, is there any way to express $\zeta_{X\wedge Y}$ in terms of $\zeta_X$ and $\zeta_Y$?
3. If $X$ and $Y$ are motivic spaces that have zeta functions $\zeta_X$ and $\zeta_Y$, and if $f:X\to Y$ is a sufficiently nice morphism, is there a way to make sense of $f_*\zeta_X$ (for example, would this be $\zeta_{f(X)}$)? If so, is there a way to relate $f_*\zeta_X$ and $\zeta_Y$?

Answer (score 9):

Etale cohomology factors through the stable $\mathbb A^1$ homotopy type. So you should simply consider your local zeta factor in terms of traces of frobenius on etale cohomology.  Since smashing with $\mathbb P^1$ corresponds to tensoring with $\mathbb Q_l(q)$  the eigenvalues that give you the local factor will be multiplied by $q$ each time. This means that the local factor will undergo the transformation $f(t) \mapsto f(qt)$. In terms of the global zeta function, this should correspond to translating by $1$.

Comment: I suppose this is answered by your first sentence, but does this mean that two weakly equivalent spaces will have the same global zeta function? I was worried that contracting $\mathbb{A}^1$ would change the set of points over which the Euler product is taken.

Comment: @StephenMcKean Of course $\mathbb A^1$ and $*$ don't have the same zeta function. Two *proper* spaces that are weakly equivalent have the same zeta function.  The zeta function depends on the compactly supported cohomology, which does not factor through the $\mathbb A^1$ homotopy category. But for proper varieties, compactly supported cohomology agrees with ordinary cohomology,  hence factors through the homotopy category.

Comment: Great, thanks for your clear explanations!